# .htaccess multiple rewrite condtion - using first condition matched parts in second condition

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, conditional-statements

Can I use first conditions matched items in second condition.

Ex -:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != (First condition matched item)
```

Update -

My sample htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /assets
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).dam.nissanka.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /assets/%1/dam/collection/a.txt? [L,R=301]
```

url trying - www.dam.nissanka.com/assets/dam/collection/a.txt

This redirects recursively to www.dam.nissanka.com/www/assets/dam/collection/a.txt. I need to stop the recursion

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web server configuration, not software development.

Comment: @anubhava I need to add first condition matched item to my rewrite rule. If i do that it recursively redirects(without second condition). I have subfolders according to the subdomain(www, abc). I need to hide that part from url and rewrite it according to the subdomain to relevent folder

Comment: As I suggested lot of tricks are possible but you need to add clear requirements with examples in question.

Comment: @anubhava I updated my question. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both conditions into one and use a back-reference to earlier captured group like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.[^:]+:(?!/\1/).*$
```

**Your .htaccess can be this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /assets/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.[^:]+:/assets/(?!\1/).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/dam/collection/a.txt? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: I added this line to my htaccess. It redirects correctly but it recursively redirects and after several redirects it gives The page isn't redirecting properly error

Comment: Well this is direct answer of combining 2 rewrite conditions but since I still don't know what exactly are you trying to do that's why I couldn't give you full rule.

Comment: Updated. Added the htaccess file content